# Queryset comparision inside a template, maybe using custom version of {% ifchanged %} tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two models as follows:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    # ...

class Paragraph(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    # ...
```

Inside a template I'm iterating through queryset of `Paragraph` objects to display them, using `{% for %}` tag. I also need to display related tags, but only if they are diffrent from previous iteration.
This means that if I'm rendering list of 5 paragraphs, and the first four of them have identical tags, but the fifth one have diffrent tags, I want to display the tags only by the first and the fifth paragraph.

I tried to use [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) build-in tag, but as I figured out, I can't use `{% ifchanged paragraph.tags.all %}` because it will always return `True`, even if `paragraph.tags.all` contains the same elements.

So I think of witing a custom template tag `{% iftagschanged %}` at the base of `{% ifchanged %}` tag, but using diffrent method of comparision, that compares querysets content insted of querysets themselves, which would always not match.
Problem is, that as I looked at [`{% ifchanged %}` tag in django source](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaulttags.py#L240), it looks a bit complicated to me, and I can't find out, how to change it to work properly in my case.

So I'll be thankfull for advice or maybe an idea of any diffrent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom method on the Paragraph model that returns its associated tags in a datastructure that can be easily compared - say, a set - and use that as the argument to ifchanged.

```
class Paragraph(models.Model):
    def tags_as_set(self):
        return set(t.tag for t in self.tags.all())


{% ifchanged paragraph.tags_as_set %}
```